# What is the origin of "Program to an interface, not an implementation"?

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces, history, implementations

What is the origin of "Program to an interface, not an implementation"?

Does it originate from Design Patterns, 1994, by GoF, or from a computer scientist or from some concepts in computer science earlier?

Comment: I always thought it was fallout from the design-by-contact practice followed by Bertram Meyer's Eiffel language, but it could be older.

Comment: Voting to close because this is more of a bibliographic question.  The concept of programming to an interface and ignoring the implementation goes back to the first time someone wrote a subroutine and didn't give the callers the source.  (Figure some time in the 1950s.)

Comment: Are "bibliographic" questions off-topic on programmers?  This question is not asking to recommend a book, it is asking for the first reference to a particular practice.  I bet there are tons of questions like that here.

Comment: @MikeNakis the answer is one that will come from one's skill at [searching google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=program+to+an+interface&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprogram%20to%20an%20interface%3B%2Cc0) - not so much one's experience at software design.

Comment: @MichaelT I think that's still legitimate. Someone will exercise their google skills, some people will learn something new, everyone wins.

Comment: @MikeNakis:  My take on this is that it's more of a "find me the earliest mention of X in the literature" question, which is subtly different from [this one](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/253694/where-did-the-notion-of-calling-a-function-come-from), which asks where X originated.  Much of what's in _Design Patterns_ had been done for years without giving it names.  Their true origins are probably much less in the literature and more in someone having done them or the first time and shared the ideas by word of mouth.

Comment: "The concept of programming to an interface and ignoring the implementation goes back to the first time someone wrote a subroutine and didn't give the callers the source."... actually, that's not what "Program to an interface, not an implementation" means, as I understand it

Answer (score 6):

"Program to an interface, not an implementation" is succinct way of describing a process by which to build software, and this formulation is largely attributed to the Gang of Four.

However, the process they were describing has its roots far earlier, and originates from [Kent Beck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_Beck) and [Ward Cunningham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward_Cunningham) who came up with the idea of using "pattern languages" (a concept attributed to [Christopher Alexander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Alexander), an architect) to write object-oriented programs.

From their [OOPSLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OOPSLA)-87 talk, "[Using Pattern Languages for Object-Oriented Programs](http://c2.com/doc/oopsla87.html)":

> We propose a radical shift in the burden of design and implementation, using concepts adapted from the work of Christopher Alexander, an architect and founder of the Center for Environmental Structures. Alexander proposes homes and offices be designed and built by their eventual occupants. These people, he reasons, know best their requirements for a particular structure. We agree, and make the same argument for computer programs. Computer users should write their own programs. The idea sounds foolish when one considers the size and complexity of both buildings and programs, and the years of training for the design professions. Yet Alexander offers a convincing scenario. It revolves around a concept called a "pattern language."
>
> A pattern language guides a designer by providing workable solutions to all of the problems known to arise in the course of design. It is a sequence of bits of knowledge written in a style and arranged in an order which leads a designer to ask (and answer) the right questions at the right time. Alexander encodes these bits of knowledge in written patterns, each sharing the same structure. Each has a statement of a problem, a summary of circumstances creating the problem and, most important, a solution that works in those circumstances. A pattern language collects the patterns for a complete structure, a residential building for example, or an interactive computer program. Within a pattern language, patterns connect to other patterns where decisions made in one influence the others. A written pattern includes these connections as prologue and epilogue. Alexander has shown that nontrivial languages can be organized without cycles in their influence and that this allows the design process to proceed without any need for reversing prior decisions.